# Is express similar to grunt? what is the difference? what are the advantages of express over grunt?

Tags: node.js, express, gruntjs, mean-stack

I've been working on node,grunt,bower and yeoman from couple of months. I came across MEAN stack applications, in which expressjs is providing the server environment(my understanding). Are both grunt and express similar?

Requesting for some helpful link on express and MEAN stack.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Express](http://expressjs.com/) is a webserver framework on top of nodejs (like symphony for php).

[Grunt](http://gruntjs.com/) is an automation tool (like make or gulp) and not a webserver.

The only thing they have in common is, that they use the JavaScript programming language.

[MEAN](http://mean.io/#!/) is a full stack environment for developing web applications. MEAN uses MongoDB as database backend, Express as webserver framework, AngularJs for the client side and all is based on NodeJs. When your application gets more complex and you need some sort of deployment procedure you may use Grunt to automate this.

Comment: Any helpful links for MEAN stack